# Spring MVC + Hibernate + JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I'm new using these tools so you'll probably find this very stupid.

I'm getting this error, when trying to access my webapp (where I'm supposed to show every user in my database "User" table.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /maven-archetype-webapp/index. Reason:

    Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute
Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.usuario_jsp._jspx_meth_form_label_0(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.usuario_jsp:299)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.usuario_jsp._jspx_meth_form_form_1(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.usuario_jsp:222)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.usuario_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.usuario_jsp:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

So I'm gonna send you my Controller, my JSP and my Service implementation.

UsuarioController.java

```
package org.maven.archetypes.Project.controller;


import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.maven.archetypes.Project.form.Usuario;
import org.maven.archetypes.Project.service.UsuarioService;


@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
     private UsuarioService usuarioService;
    @RequestMapping("/index")
     public String listUsers(Map<String, Object> map) {
            map.put("usuario", new Usuario());
            map.put("usuarioList", usuarioService.listUsuario());
            return "usuario";
     } 


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String addUsuario(@ModelAttribute("user")
        Usuario user, BindingResult result) {
        usuarioService.addUsuario(user);
        return "redirect:/index";
     }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{email}")
     public String deleteUsuario(@PathVariable("email")
     String email) {
            usuarioService.removeUsuario(email);
            return "redirect:/index";
     }

}
```

Usuario.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- 

<h3>Usuarios</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty usuarioList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
 <th><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></th>
 <th><spring:message code="label.email"/></th>
 <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${usuarioList}" var="usuario">
 <tr>
 <td>${usuario.lastname}, ${usuario.firstname} </td>
 <td>${usuario.email}</td>
 <td><a href="delete/${usuario.email}">Eliminar</a></td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if> 

</body>
</html>
```

UsuarioServiceImpl.java (implementation of the interface UsuarioService.java)

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService {

     @Autowired
     private UsuarioDAO UsuarioDAO;

     @Transactional
     public void addUsuario(Usuario user) {
     UsuarioDAO.addUsuario(user);
     }

     @Transactional
     public List<Usuario> listUsuario() {

     return UsuarioDAO.listUsuario();
     }

     @Transactional
     public void removeUsuario(String email) {
     UsuarioDAO.removeUsuario(email);
     }  

}
```

I don't know if it's necessary to keep going with the DAOs ... the problem is that the error names a "Contact" and I don't even use that name in anything at all (I use "Usuario"). And yes, before you ask, I did replace some internet code which did have the word "contact" but I replaced them all to my code. So maybe this caused a mess but I'm really lost now. Hope you can help me. If there's something you don't understand don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: i think you have messed up your deployed code which you said you took from some tutorial online.i guess you deployed that war in your server and you made changes on top of the code and tried to redeploy again. so what i would say is delete the already deployed war, restart your server. do a clean maven build once again and redeploy it and check

Comment: I'm sorry but, how do I delete the already deployed war? (I told you I'm a real newbie).

Comment: if you are using Tomcat go to /webapps/ folder and delete your deployed war from there google in case you have issues. if you use weblogic app server open the weblogic console, go to the deployment section where your war is deployed and uninstall it. you can google for this also how its to be done. before doing all this stop your server(not required for weblogic).

Comment: I tried but nothing works. I'm using Jetty and there's nothing in the webapp directory of jetty_home. I searched for something on tmp folders in system but no clue ... Googled it and nothing. I'm really on the edge now. I even made a whole new project, with the same code of the old one. Same error.

Comment: not sure in Jetty how you can do that but there would be a way. but the last option what i think is check everywhere in your project i mean xml files, property files,.java files if you can find contact may be you have missed it somewhere. bro this is all i can help sitting here as i cannot see your code,what you are doing and how you are running it.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do..and no worries, I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are only putting your object into a map. You need to put your objects in http request. Spring has model objects **Model** and **ModelAndView** that do this as shown below:-

```
<code>
@RequestMapping("/index")
     public String listUsers(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("usuario", new Usuario());
            model.addAttribute("usuarioList", usuarioService.listUsuario());
            return "usuario";
     }

</code>
```

OR

```
<code>
@RequestMapping("/index")
     public ModelAndView listUsers() {
           ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("usuario");
            mav.addObject("usuario", new Usuario());
            mav.addObject("usuarioList", usuarioService.listUsuario());
            return mav;
     }
 </code>
```

Comment: But those mav.put or model.put are not even defined in the Model and ModelandView object types.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have updated the answer with correct methods.

Comment: Ok thank you for answering but it didn't help. Same problem. Notice that the error is about a Model that doesn't even exists, so it must be a problem with the cached war file in Jetty or something, probably an old deployed war which had the model name "contact" before I changed it. Some people below said it but I've still no solution :/

Comment: Can you post your web.xml and spring configuration files?

Comment: I already solved it. Actually I didn't, but I threw off Jetty and started using Tomcat, which is significately better for me. Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest you here is delete the target folder where the build is prepared and recreate the build and war and then run, if problem persists then let us know with the necessary files. Thanks

Comment: I did what you told me, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you delete the cached files in ur server, say in work folder of tomcat, temp folder and try again

Comment: Didn't help. Don't know if I did it wrong, but I deleted all caches I could find in Jetty_Home. Clean the maven project and re-build it. As a matter of fact, I also created a whole new project with the same code. Same error always. The "contact" keeps getting in the way :/